# Simple SQL aggregation of rows where values are arrays of integer

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to modify my table to something slightly different.
Bellow is my table where `langs` contains the same array for every rows. (Always `[Dutch, English, French]`).

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ['French','English','Dutch'] langs, [0, 2, 1] as value Union ALL
SELECT ['French','English','Dutch'], [1, 0, 1]
```

The output looks like:

```
Row langs          value
-------------------------
1   Dutch          1
    English        2
    French         0
-------------------------
2   Dutch          1
    English        3
    French         0
-------------------------
```

Now I want to sum up value array over all the rows and create another table with value column representing total values.
But the version I am looking for is like bellow:

```
Row langs          value
-------------------------
1   Dutch          2  # (1+1)
-------------------------
2   English        5  # (2+3)
-------------------------
3   French         1  # (1+0)
-------------------------
```

I know this might look like a very dump question but I am extremely new to SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT lang, SUM(val) total
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST(langs) lang WITH OFFSET
JOIN UNNEST(value) val WITH OFFSET
USING(OFFSET)
GROUP BY lang
```

You can test, play with above using dummy/sample data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT ['French','English','Dutch'] langs, [1, 2, 1] AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT ['French','English','Dutch'], [0, 3, 1]
)
SELECT lang, SUM(val) total
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST(langs) lang WITH OFFSET
JOIN UNNEST(value) val WITH OFFSET
USING(OFFSET)
GROUP BY lang
```

with result

```
Row lang    total    
1   French  1    
2   English 5    
3   Dutch   2
```

Comment: Although, it answers the above question, the solution doesn't work for the following:
`SELECT ['French','EEEnglish','Dutch'], [0, 3, 1]`

Comment: When you say ‘doesn’t work’ - what is exactly you mean?

Comment: It will return `EEEnglish  --> 3` which is actually 1. Same for field 'English' for which it returns 2.

Comment: I don’t see your logic now - 3 is exactly what I would expect for eeenglish!

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Confused by another question.